# discord python (bot.command with int check)

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext.commands import bot

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The 'Superbot' is now online.")

@bot.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount):
    amount = int(amount)
    if amount == int:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    elif amount != int:
        return await ctx.send("!Clear [Integer]")
bot.run('removed')`
```

EnyoS:
!clear dfk
Superbot:
The Command raised an exception: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'dfk'

EnyoS:
!clear 10
Superbot:
!Clear [Integer]

I want to make it return `!Clear [Integer]` and when I write a number it just works, thanks ahead!

Comment: `if amount == int:` does not work. Do you mean `if type(amount) is int:`?

Answer (score 0):

Try and Except ValueError. The format for this is: `Try: amount = int(amount) Except ValueError: await ctx.send("!Clear [Integer]")` This removes the need for the if statement too. The indentation doesn't quite come across well, but this will help: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Comment: but that's not what I am aking, I am trying to make the (amount) as an int so u can't cuz even when u write an number it still counts that as a sting

Comment: Maybe try ```async def clear(ctx, amount = int):``` then?

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna want to check if the argument passed can be cast to an `int`.

```
@bot.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount):
    try:
        amount = int(amount)
        return await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    except ValueError:
        return await ctx.send("!Clear [Integer]")
```

> but that's not what I am aking, I am trying to make the (amount) as an int so u can't cuz even when u write an number it still counts that as a sting

I'm not 100% sure what you mean with this, but I think my answer does what you need. This way, when you pass in a number, which will indeed be a `string`, it will try to cast it to an `int` to see if it's an actual number (and not some random text). Going off of your `error message`, which sends the command usage, this *is* what you want.